# iOS 10 [AVAudioSession privateInterruptionWithInfo:] crash

Tags: ios10, avaudiosession

The new version has a large number of crashes on iOS 10.

The message is

> SEGV_ACCERR
>
> libobjc.A.dylib objc_msgSend

There are two kinds of crashes.

1:

```
libobjc.A.dylib objc_msgSend + 16
AVFAudio    -[AVAudioSession privateInterruptionWithInfo:] + 172
AVFAudio    (anonymous namespace)::HandlePropertyListenerCallback(unsigned int, objc_selector*, NSObject*) + 92
libdispatch.dylib   __dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
libdispatch.dylib   __dispatch_client_callout + 16
libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1000
CoreFoundation  ___CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
CoreFoundation  ___CFRunLoopRun + 1660
CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal + 180
UIKit   -[UIApplication _run] + 684
UIKit   UIApplicationMain + 208
MyApplication   main (main.m:16)
libdyld.dylib   _start + 4
```

2:

```
libobjc.A.dylib objc_msgSend + 28
libAVFAudio.dylib   -[AVAudioSession privateBeginInterruption] + 60
Foundation  ___NSThreadPerformPerform + 340
CoreFoundation  ___CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
CoreFoundation  ___CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 412
CoreFoundation  ___CFRunLoopRun + 724
CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal + 180
UIKit   UIApplicationMain + 204
MyApplication   main (main.m:16)
libdyld.dylib   _start + 4
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The delegate property is deprecated in `AVAudioSession` and it is replaced with a Notification `AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification`. So rather using delegate property register for this notification. Image depicting the same from header of `AVAudioSession.h` -

[image: AVAudioSession_Deprecated_Delegate_Property_iOS_10_]